# Easiest way to check if file exists within a subfolder

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

I am going getting all the folders within a folder as follows:

```
foreach (DirectoryInfo directory in root.GetDirectories())
```

I now want to check all the files in each of those folder individualally for an XML file.If the XML file exists I want to do something.

What would be the best way to go about this?

I know this is the basis:

```
   if (File.Exists("*.xml"))
        {

        }
```

but that is not working?

Comment: It's not working because the folder contains a xml file but it is skipping right over the if statement when stepping through it.

Comment: I've written a more detailed response below, but if you want the "teach a man to fish" answer...consider that you have nothing tethering the DirectoryInfos that you're iterating through to the static call you're making to the File class (ie File is just doing the same thing every time through that loop, it doesn't care that you're switching DirectoryInfos)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this method if you want to actually do something with the XML file.  If you are just checking to see if any xml file exists then I would go a different route:

```
foreach (DirectoryInfo directory in root.GetDirectories())
{
    foreach(string file in Directory.GetFiles(directory.FullName, "*.xml"))
    {
      //if you get in here then do something with the file
      //an "if" statement is not necessary.
    }
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The [Directory.GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f.aspx) method:

```
if (Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\","*.xml").Length > 0) {
    // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you could use [`Directory.GetFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316.aspx) with your search pattern and action upon the found files...

```
var existing = Directory.GetFiles(root, "*.xml", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

//...

foreach(string found in existing) {
    //TODO: Action upon the file etc..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    foreach (DirectoryInfo directory in root.GetDirectories())
    {
        // What you have here would call a static method on the File class that has no knowledge 
        // at all of your directory object, if you want to use this then give it a fully qualified path
        // and ignore the directory calls altogether
        //if (File.Exists("*.xml"))

        FileInfo[] xmlFiles = directory.GetFiles("*.xml");
        foreach (var file in xmlFiles)
        {
          // do whatever   
        }
    }
```